# Why my setState() behaves unpredictably with my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

A few days ago I started learning react and here I ran into a problem. I have two elements on my website. Input field and submit button. There are two functions for these two elements, inputValue function and the submitField function.
The problem is that the inputValue console.log () function does not show the first change to the input field in the console. This means that if I type the letter "a", console.log will show me an empty output. The output is displayed only after entering the next letters, but with a delay of one letter.
The problem with the submitField function is that when I use setState instead of simply using the push method on the list array, the first click on the submit button adds nothing to the array. There is no problem with using the push method. I put the code below:

INDEX.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

APP.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ListInput from './ListInput';
import './index.css';

class App extends Component { // jest to nowy syntax - nie trzeba tworzyć już konstruktora i używać super do dziedziczenia po obiekcie nadrzędnym. Wystarczy tak jak jest tutaj
    state = {
      inputField: '',
      list: []
    }
  
  inputValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({inputField: event.target.value}); 
    console.log(this.state.inputField); // this not showing first change on input field - why? ex. if i put 'a' in input field i got blank console.log.
  }

  submitField = () => {
    this.setState({list:[this.state.inputField]}) // this working with one click delay- on first try returning empty array on consol.log, even if inputField state is modified
    // this.state.list.push(this.state.inputField);  // this working fine - adding  element to list array on first try
    console.log(this.state.list);
    
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ListInput submit={this.submitField} input={this.inputValue}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

LISTINPUT.JS COMPONENT with events

```
import React from 'react';

const ListInput = ({submit, input}) => {
    return (
        <div className='list-input'>
            <input onChange={input} type='text' placeholder='add item' />
            <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ListInput;
```

Can somebody explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState()` is async ([React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value)), so the state changes won't be applied immediately. If you want console.log the new state,`setState()` takes in a function as the second argument and performs that function when the state is updated. So:

```
this.setState({ 
    abc: xyz 
  }, 
  () => console.log(this.state.abc),
)
```